# File.WriteAllBytes does not changes file to binary 10101011

Tags: c#, io, binary

I have a some confusion about the function File.WriteAllBytes.

Actually i read from an image file using

```
byte[] b =  System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(textBox1.Text);
```

and then i wrote back the read data to a text file to see how it looks.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\abc.txt", b);
```

But the contents of abc.txt are not pure binary(1010110) , but they appear as :-

ëžÕwN±k›“ùIRA=Ï¥DhÔ¨í»™Êj:³0Æî(À÷«3ÚÉid¤n•O<‰-ª@–¢)cùY³Ö˜K„TûËEÇóþ}wtÑ+²=£v*NÌ!\    äji;âíÇ8ÿ ?çŠ´ö¬€Áç#µ:+ŠVÜ„©³Û?çù~VèÖ·ÂËSŠE7RH8}GJGfT?Ý?çüÿ œÌÊR"6­ÓŠY¬Š¬L§|n¹> ÷’ÃU{D®t­vE!3** Ý× õ¨ã(¨qžO§ùÿ >Ó¥¤…K€@N{ñM(ÊÅ€ûÃŒRtj/²Æ¤¶¹RÁŽxqþÏó@KŒînçš˜æ0C/-Ž1Mu>oÊ }é5(­Q¢i±pIôÀôÿ ?çÒÂB-á.ãï©Ú}êB®æÇÌyÿ ?çüU¥mã$”ã
‚DiFQ¸'µ,ARGLäc¯4%ËŸÃœsŸóù~H 3d‚zŠ‡Ø........................................

Are the binary 1s and 0s getting converted to some other number system comprising of so many symbols ??

Comment: If you read all bytes, don't change anything, and then write all bytes to another file, then it only makes sense to me that you get the same file. I can understand thinking that `WriteAllBytes` does something else, but I can't understand thinking that `ReadAllBytes` followed by `WriteAllBytes` creates a completely different file.

Comment: file is the same .Its just the way i am opening the file. If you try to open an image in a textpad or notepad , it would appear as above. But i am intrested in looking 1s and 0s

Comment: Open the file in a hex editor and you will see the bytes. You won't see 1s and 0s but rather the hex values (0-F).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A text-viewer like NotePad will try to interpret the bytes as text, probably it will interpret the bytes as [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

If you want to see the actual 0's and 1's then read in the image as bytes and convert the byte array to a string of 0's and 1's, for this you could use:

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
   string hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
   return hex.Replace("-","");
}
```

The conversion function is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa) (accepted answer). Remember, this string will not anymore be interpretable as image, essentially this will simply be a large string of 0's and 1's.

Comment: Yes it worked . Now the text file outputs as FFD8FFE000104A4649460001010100C800C80000FFE114084578696600004D4D002A00000008000C010F00020000000348500...

Answer (score 1):

Each byte in the file is comprised of 8 bits. When you use `ReadAllBytes`, you get an array of `byte` instances, where each `byte` represents a number between `0` and `255` (inclusive). One representation of the number 86 that is readable by humans is `01010110`. However, when you use `WriteAllBytes`, it writes the sequence of bytes in the original form. Notepad is then loading the file and displaying each byte as a single character (or in [some encodings treating multiple bytes as a single character to display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)). However, if you were to write "01010110" to a file such that Notepad shows those numbers, you would actually end up writing 8 *bytes*, not 8 *bits*, like this, where each set of 8 bits represents the digit '0' or '1':

```
00110000 00110001 00110000 00110001 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000
```

Comment: This makes sense if there are only 256 unique symbols in the converted file.